# Break loop execution for particular index from function call in python, then continue

Tags: function, for-loop, python-2.6

My problem is as follows:

```
lst=[1,2,3,4,5]
lst_pass=[1,2,5]
count=0
flag=0
print "flag1"
print type(flag)


def fn1(lst_fn,j):
    if lst_fn[j] in lst_pass:
        print("pass")
        pass
    #if fail do not perform whatever is below fn call instead append index of for loop and check for next element

    else:
        flag=1
        return flag


print("code_prior")

for i in range(len(lst)):
    print lst[i]

    flag=fn1(lst,i)

    if flag!=1:
        print("code_after ")
        print lst[i] 

    flag=0
```

1)If pass then just execute whatever is after fn call 2)In this case 1,2 pass hence code_after should get printed for both 3)  j=3 code_after shouldn't get printed, as 3 isn't there in lst_pass; instead for loop should execute for 4  4)4 is also not in lst_pass so code_after shouldn't get printed, instead for loop should execute for 5 5) 5 in lst_pass so ideally code_after should get printed thrice

The above code works fine with the crude flag method, however the code I have to execute following the same is huge and calls many fns thereafter. Is there an elegant way to do the same? I am working with python 2.6. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

What I could understand from you code is that you trying to loop through lst and check if its in lst_pass and then print them.

Just modify your code to:

```
print("code_prior")
for i in range(len(lst)):
  if lst[i] in lst_pass:
    print("code_after ")
    print lst[i]
```

There is no need to declare a separate function for this logic.

Comment: My code is actually meant for validation..I'm declaring that fn to eliminate proxy members. The code after print("code_after ") is a lot so I was looking for a better way to handle it than flags..thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
"code before"

flag = fn1 (lst,i)

if flag==1: 
    continue

"code after"
```

Comment: I would like to remove my flags entirely..I can definitely use continue too, thanks anyway!